# MySQL Filter on many-to-many on recipes - ingredients tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

In my application, I have 3 tables:

1. recipes

```
-id
-name
-description
```

2. ingredients

```
-id
-name
```

3. recipes_ingredients

```
-recipes_id
-ingredients_id
```

I need to find all those recipes that contain a list of ingredients_id and that I have in my food storage and containing **NO OTHERS** ids outside the list  I provided (so not in my food storage).

Example: i provide oil (id=111) bread=(id=222) result recipes:

- **OK** *oil+bread*
- **OK** *bread*
- **OK** *oil*
- **NO** *oil+ salt*
- **NO** *bread + oil + salt*

this query IT DOESN'T WORKS because it gives me back the recipes that have exclusively and exactly the ingredients provided:

```
SELECT ri.recipes_id
FROM recipes_ingredients ri
WHERE ri.ingredients_id IN (111,222)
GROUP BY ri.recipes_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

I also tried to change HAVING COUNT in

```
HAVING COUNT(*) <= length_of_list_I_provided
```

but he gives me back all the recipes that, yes, have even only a part of the ingredients supplied but also the ingredients that I have not provided it in the list.

Do you have any ideas?

thanks and regards

**UPDATE:**

as they suggested to me, I show you an example of tables:

Recipes table:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Recipe 1 |
| 2 | Recipe 2 |
| 3 | Recipe 3 |
| 4 | Recipe 4 |
| 5 | Recipe 5 |
| 6 | Recipe 6 |

Ingredients table:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Oil |
| 222 | Bread |
| 333 | Salt |
| 444 | Pepper |

Recipes_Ingredients table:

| RECIPES_ID | INGREDIENTS_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 |
| 1 | 222 |
| 2 | 222 |
| 3 | 222 |
| 3 | 333 |
| 4 | 111 |
| 4 | 222 |
| 4 | 333 |
| 5 | 333 |
| 5 | 444 |
| 6 | 111 |

In the query I give it my ingredients

```
IN(111,222)
```

It must return:

| RECIPE_ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 6 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So maybe you can use this query

```
SELECT ri.recipes_id
FROM recipes_ingredients ri
GROUP BY ri.recipes_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ri.ingredients_id NOT IN (111,222) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) =0;
```

[demo fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7803e558b99741cb3a5fb7426e435452)